# Selenium select specific content with OR/AND operators - python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am struggling with a problem in Selenium using Python.

This is a dummy draft of what I have.

```
<body>
    <button info="content1" aria-label="1">"Click 1"</button>
    <button info="content1" aria-label="2">"Click 2"</button>
    <button info="content2" aria-label="2">"Click 2"</button>
    <button info="content2" aria-label="4">"Click 4"</button>
<body>
```

My target is to select the button that has `info="content1"` and `aria-label="2"`

I have already tried

```
element=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[info="content1"] and button[aria-label="2"]')
```

But doesn't work and returns  NoSuchElementException

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put the two bracketed attribute selectors next to each other with no `and`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[info="content1"][aria-label="2"]')
```